# bash: Getting error while executing curl request

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I am trying to execute a bash script but I am getting this error:

```
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 1
```

I have tried several things, like escaping the " in json, using -g in curl request, using `` around Req variable instead of using eval, but I am unable to fix this.

```
   #!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
URL='http://localhost:8983/contentCleaner?action=clean'
while read -r requestParam; do
   Req="curl ${URL} -X POST -H 'Accept:application/json' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' --data \"$requestParam\""
    Res=eval $Req
    echo "Res:$Res"
done < "$filename"
```

The file I am passing as param to the bash command contains a list of json data which is separated by new line. The bash script loops through the json and populates the curl request. Here is a sample of one request:

```
{ \"batchRequest\": { \"requests\": [ { \"contentData\": { \"contentText\": { \"ingestedContentSummary\": { \"provider\": { \"url\": \"twitter.com\" }, \"title\": \"Trump\" } } }, \"contentSource\": \"twitter\", } ] } }
```

Comment: Have you tried double quotes around `${URL}`? `Req="curl \"${URL}\" ...`

Comment: @mouviciel yes i have tried that but still got the same error

Comment: @mouviciel: The variable `URL` does not contain spaces; double-quoting can't have any effect.

Comment: @user1934428 - Agreed. I'm used to quote URLs with curl because of `&` characters, which are absent here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't (try to) put shell commands in (scalar) variables.** It only works for the very simplest cases, and your case isn't very simple. We have *lots* of previous Qs with this problem, but unfortunately they're hard to search for. Instead as a reference see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 .

For your case, just execute the correct command:

```bash
while read -r requestParam; do
   Res=$( curl ${URL} -H 'Accept:application/json' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' --data "$requestParam" ) # -X POST 
    echo "Res:$Res"
done < $filename
```

You don't need `-X POST` because all `--data*` options automatically set it. Also, <$var (and >$var >>$var <<$var <<<$var) are *not* subject to wordsplitting and globbing so don't need double-quoting. (In contrast `"$requestParam"` as a command argument does.)

Or since the only thing you are doing with the result is outputting it with a prefix, you can simplify to

```bash
while read -r requestParam; do
   curl ${URL} -H 'Accept:application/json' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' --data "$requestParam" | sed 's/^/Res:/'
done <$filename
```

and *if* each body has a newline (like your input file) further to

```bash
xargs <$filename -I{} curl $URL -H... -H... --data {} | sed 's/^/Res:/'
```

Comment: You still need double quotes around the URL, otherwise this will fail if it contains e.g. `&`. See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that if the OP **does** want to use a variable for holding the command, and array might help.